# Publishing split up assembly packages

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm using `sbt-assembly` to publish artifacts. But I have added configuration split up artifacts into code and dependencies packages.

The instructions on the sbt-assembly page mentions how to add assembly to the publishing phase.

However I only get the `-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` published, not the -`assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar`.

How to I add the `deps.jar` to publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically repeat the steps using `packageDependency`:

```
artifact in (Compile, packageDependency) ~= { art =>
  art.copy(`classifier` = Some("deps"))
}

addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, packageDependency), packageDependency)
```